# Stylus Iteration + Interpolation with nth-of-type

Tags: iteration, interpolation, stylus

I'm attempting to use the counter provided when looping thru a list of items like so:

```
colors = red blue orange green yellow

li
    for color, i in colors
        &:nth-of-type({i}n)
            background-color: color
```

This example does not work, but the intended output I'm looking for is:

```
li:nth-of-type(1n) {
    background-color: red;
}
li:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background-color: blue;
}
li:nth-of-type(3n) {
    background-color: orange;
}
...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your example's output is almost correct. It starts with 0 and you need 1, so this should work:

```
colors = red blue orange green yellow

li
    for color, i in colors
        &:nth-of-type({i + 1}n)
            background-color: color
```